# AJAX Live Search Using jQuery Only Runs Once

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is a script used to run a live search.

```
<script>
    $(".search").keyup(function() {

        var Team_Name = $('#TeamName').val();
        var Teacher = $('#Teacher').val();

        var Search_Data = Team_Name + '?????' + Teacher;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Student Search Results.php",
            data: {
                query: Search_Data
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                alert('The values were sent');
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<?php

include "Student Search Results.php";

?>
```

The live search is functioning fine except for that it does not repeat (it only runs once when the page first loads). Are there any ideas as to why this may be? Thank you.

Comment: are you loading some html content

Comment: Later in my code, I include the php function that makes use of the variables I post. The final result is a table, so yes, it is HTML content.

Comment: check you data and /or check ajax request in web developer tools line in firebug or chrome or fiddler

Comment: Sometimes the ajax post will be 200 ok but response is error. Check error in ajax. I had case with JSON dataType. Try explicitly specifying dataType: 'html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing a static process with a dynamic one.  `<?php include() ?>` is going to run at the server initially and will not be executed again on that page.  No matter how many times your AJAX function submits data, your page will never change because it was already loaded long ago.

What you need to do is leave that `include()` out completely and use JSON or XML to reply through the PHP file directly into that `$.ajax()` function.

Then you can use jQuery/JS to parse the data into something pretty and organized.

---

Here's a little more detail:

On your PHP page you're going to listen for a `$_POST['query']` and run your function as usual.  But instead of printing it however your PHP page is now, you need to separate the markup part of that page from the PHP execution.

You'll then take that markup and place it underneath your script in the same place you currently have `<?php include(); ?>`.  For jQuery to update this on-demand as you'd like, change:

```
...
success: function() {
   alert();
}
```

to pass the returned data from the PHP page like this:

```
...
success: function(data) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i in data) {
        $('#searchResults').find('.resultNumber').append(i++);
        $('#searchResults').find('.team-name').append(data.teamName);
        $('#searchResults').find('.teacher').append(data.teacher);
    }
}
```

And down here is a `<table id="searchResults">` and some `<td>`s and `<tr>`s, etc.